# How do I position widgets inside a card contained in a row?

Tags: dart, flutter

Currently, I am trying to create a card template to insert into a list view. I want the column with the icon buttons to be positioned on the far right. I cannot seem to find a way to say that the column containing the icon buttons needs to be flushed to the right.

```
new Expanded(
            child: new ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0),
              children: <Widget>[
                new Card(
                  child: new Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0),
                      ),
                      new Image(
                        //image: new AssetImage("assets/ic_access_alarm_red_24dp.png"),
                        image: new AssetImage("assets/pastDue.png"),
                        height: 50.0,
                        width: 50.0,
                      ),
                      new Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0),
                      ),
                      new Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Text("This is the title"),
                          new Text("This is the Description"),
                          new Text("This is the date"),
                        ],
                      ),
                      new Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new IconButton(
                            icon: new Icon(Icons.note_add),
                            onPressed: () {
                              select("AddCalibration");
                            }
                          ),
                          new IconButton(
                            icon: new Icon(Icons.edit),
                            onPressed: () {
                              select("EditInstrument");
                            }
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ),

                const Text("I am"),
                const Text("A ListView"),
              ],
            )
          )
```

[This is a capture of what it currently looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eALcp.png)

Comment: In the ListTile widget  https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html
you can use the `trailing` property to show your Icon

Comment: I meant 'leading' property

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I still have a lot more to learn about flutter.

Comment: A card has an image, i want to add favorite icon at top right positioned of card to do like/dislike, how to can set it by positioned? Please suggest me.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you, vbandrade!

This definitely solved my problem.

```
new Expanded(
              child: new ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0),
            children: <Widget>[
              new Card(
                child: new ListTile(
                  leading: new Image(
                    image: new AssetImage("assets/pastDue.png"),
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: 50.0,
                  ),
                  title: new Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text("This is the title"),
                      new Text("This is the Description"),
                      new Text("This is the date"),
                    ],
                  ),
                  trailing: new Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new IconButton(
                          icon: new Icon(Icons.note_add),
                          onPressed: () {
                            select("AddCalibration");
                          }),
                      new IconButton(
                          icon: new Icon(Icons.edit),
                          onPressed: () {
                            select("EditInstrument");
                          })
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const Text("I am"),
              const Text("A ListView"),
            ],
          ))
```

[This is the end result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXMeD.png)

Answer (score 0):

use the Expanded widget to push the icons to the right

```
new Expanded(child: new Container())
```

so in your example :
new Column(

```
 children: <Widget>[
 new Text("This is the title"),
 new Text("This is the Description"),
 new Text("This is the date"),],
 ),
 new Expanded(child: new Container()),
 new Column(
 children: <Widget>[
 new IconButton(
 icon: new Icon(Icons.note_add),
 onPressed: () {}),
```